# Prove that if $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda}S_\alpha$ is a subring of $R$ then $(S,\subseteq)$ is a totally ordered set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Problem.**
>
> Let $(R,+,.)$ be a ring. Let $S:=\{S_\alpha:\alpha\in \Lambda\}$ where $S_\alpha$ is a subring of $R$ for all $\alpha\in \Lambda$. Prove that if $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda}S_\alpha$ is a subring of $R$ then $(S,\subseteq)$ is a totally ordered set.

**My Thoughts**

I thought that I would proceed by assuming that $(S,\subseteq)$ is not a totally ordered set. This would mean the existence of two subrings $S_{\beta},S_\gamma\in S$ such that neither $S_{\beta}\subseteq S_\gamma$ nor $S_\gamma\subseteq S_\beta$ is true. In other words, we have both $S_{\beta}\not\subseteq S_\gamma$ nor $S_\gamma\not\subseteq S_\beta$. Which would imply that there exists two elements $x,y$ such that $x\in S_\beta$ but $x\not\in S_{\gamma}$ and $y\in S_\gamma$ but $y\not\in S_\beta$. I wanted to show that at least one of the elements $x-y$ and $xy$ willn't belong to $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda}S_\alpha$. But there I got stuck.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is clearly false. Just take any such set that contains $R$ itself and which is not totally ordered by inclusion.

Comment: Without $R$ perhaps?

Comment: Still not. Basically it just implies that the set has a maximum element (and even this, I am not entirely sure of).

Comment: This appears to be false already with **three** subrings, see these slides http://www.math.unipd.it/~lucchini/index_files/ring.pdf

Comment: $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb F_{p^n}$ is a field.

Comment: The correct condition is 'filtered', i.e. for any two $S_\alpha, S_\beta$, there is some $S_\gamma$, which contains both.

Comment: I again checked the problem that our professor gave us and it is precisely what I have written.

Comment: @MooS That is sufficient, but is it actually necessary? (this tends not to be the case for finite examples).

Comment: No, but at least it is the weakest sufficient condition I could think of in the general case.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Actually, the other part of the problem was to show that if $(S,\subseteq)$ is a totally ordered set then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Lambda}S_\alpha$ is a subring of $R$ which is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed in comments this is wrong as stated.

One way to correct it is the following:

Let $(R,+,.)$ be a ring. Let $S:=\{S_\alpha : \alpha \in \Lambda \}$ where $S_\alpha$ is a subring of $R$ for all $\alpha \in \Lambda$. Prove that $(S , \subset)$ is a totally ordered set if and only if $\cup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} S_\alpha$ is a subring for all $\Gamma \subset \Lambda$.

$\Rightarrow$ is trivial as a subset of a totally ordered set is totally ordered.

$\Leftarrow$ is easy to prove by looking to the cases when $\Gamma$ has exactly 2 elements.

Comment: If  $ S$ be the set of all sub-rings of $ R$ ,  then $\cup S=R$ because $R\in S$.  But $S$ is not necessarily ordered by inclusion. E.g. arithmetic mod $6$ on the integers has sub-rings $\{0,2,4\}$ and $\{0,3\}.$

Comment: @user254665 Note the part about all the subsets of $S$! In your case, the subset obtained by leaving $R$ out is typically not a subring....